# Previous date selection in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have disable the previous date in bootstrap date picker but at the time of edit i want to display the save date (if the save date is previous its not showing in date field.

```
$(function () {
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',  
    minDate:new Date()    
  });
});
```

Comment: you can enable the previous date when you are editing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing:

```
minDate:new Date()
```

make it conditional, by calling a function and check if it is add or edit and on the behalf of that condition do something like:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    minDate:mdate()
});


function mdate(){
  if( 'add' )
  {
    // retrun what ever date you want
  }
  else
  {
    // retrun something else
  }
}
```

Comment: i just want to display the previous date in edit time, and disable the selection of previous date. how both can be possible at same time...?

Comment: Make a hidden filed inside the form and put some value only for edit case. Check that value to know either it is add or edit case and do what ever do you want to do

Comment: if(mode=='edit'){
  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
   format: 'YYYY-MM-DD'
  });
   }
else if(mode=='add'){
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
           format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
   minDate:new Date()
  });
}

Comment: yes, its pending.  Its showing previous date in edit time, but the same time i want to disable the selection of previous date.

Comment: guys need your suggestions, regarding above question

Comment: Still you are stuck with the same issue?

Comment: yes,Its showing previous date in edit time, but the same time i want to disable the selection of previous date. (this the issue)

Comment: Google this: `jquery datepicker restrict dates in second date field based on selected date in first date field` and check the result links

Comment: Do you have different form for Add and Edit ?

Comment: Please make a jsfiddle with the required situation and share the link here